# Not able to add active class in React.js

Tags: reactjs, toggle

I'm trying to add an active class only on click event but it's adding in all events I have three texts each should have active class when it's clicked please see what's wrong in my below code,

```
  class CategoryList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    productlist: [],
    isActive: false
  };
  comingSoon(e) {
    this.setState(activate => {
     return { productlist: data.comingsoon, isActive: !activate.isActive               };
    });
  }
  boxOffice(e) {
    this.setState(activate => {
      return { productlist: data.boxoffice, isActive: !activate.isActive };
    });
  }
  newRelease(e) {
    this.setState(activate => {
       return { productlist: data.newrelease, isActive:   !activate.isActive };
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="categoryList-container">
        <div className="categoryList-text-wrapper">
          <h5
            className={this.state.isActive ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={() => this.comingSoon(this)}
          >
            COMING SOON
          </h5>
          <h5
            className={this.state.isActive ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={() => this.boxOffice(this)}
          >
            BOX OFFICE
          </h5>
          <h5
            className={this.state.isActive ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={() => this.newRelease(this)}
          >
            NEW RELEASE
          </h5>
        </div>
```

Comment: `<h5 className={this.state.isActive ? "active" : ""} onClick={() => this.comingSoon(this)} >` you are using same `this.state.isActive` variable for all three texts .  so when `this.state.isActive` is true all three texts will be active and vice versa

Comment: Lokesh Kumar Meena can you please explain me more what's wrong in this and how can I fix it?

Comment: i have provided the answer below please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same state item for all three of the links, so they all get switch on/off at the same time.

Either use a different state item for each, or make your state item hold a distinct value depending on which link is active.

Since not two links can be active at the same time i would go with the second option, of using different values.

Something like

```js
class CategoryList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    productlist: [],
    activeSection: ''
  };
  comingSoon(e) {
    this.setState(activate => {
     return { productlist: data.comingsoon, activeSection: 'coming-soon'};
    });
  }
  boxOffice(e) {
    this.setState(activate => {
      return { productlist: data.boxoffice, activeSection: 'box-office' };
    });
  }
  newRelease(e) {
    this.setState(activate => {
       return { productlist: data.newrelease, activeSection: 'new-release' };
    });
  }
  render() {
    const {activeSection} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="categoryList-container">
        <div className="categoryList-text-wrapper">
          <h5
            className={activeSection == 'coming-soon' ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={this.comingSoon}
          >
            COMING SOON
          </h5>
          <h5
            className={activeSection == 'box-office' ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={this.boxOffice}
          >
            BOX OFFICE
          </h5>
          <h5
            className={activeSection == 'new-release' ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={this.newRelease}
          >
            NEW RELEASE
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use three different variables .

```
 class CategoryList extends React.Component {
      state = {
        productlist: [],
        isActiveComing: false,
        isActiveBox: false,
        isActiveNew: false

      };
      comingSoon(e) {
        this.setState(activate => {
         return { productlist: data.comingsoon, isActiveComing: !activate.isActiveComing               };
        });
      }
      boxOffice(e) {
        this.setState(activate => {
          return { productlist: data.boxoffice, isActiveBox: !activate.isActiveBox};
        });
      }
      newRelease(e) {
        this.setState(activate => {
           return { productlist: data.newrelease, isActiveNew:   !activate.isActiveNew};
        });
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="categoryList-container">
            <div className="categoryList-text-wrapper">
              <h5
                className={this.state.isActiveComing? "active" : ""}
                onClick={() => this.comingSoon(this)}
              >
                COMING SOON
              </h5>
              <h5
                className={this.state.isActiveBox ? "active" : ""}
                onClick={() => this.boxOffice(this)}
              >
                BOX OFFICE
              </h5>
              <h5
                className={this.state.isActiveNew ? "active" : ""}
                onClick={() => this.newRelease(this)}
              >
                NEW RELEASE
              </h5>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because your three methods `comingSoon`, `boxOffice` and `newRelease` are changing the same variable in your state. You should create one variable for each `h5` so you can handle their activation isolated.

Another solution is to create another component that renders your h5 element and import it into this one.

Answer (score 2):

```
 class CategoryList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    productlist: [],
    isActive: 0
  };
  comingSoon(e) {
    this.setState(activate => {
     return { productlist: data.comingsoon, isActive: 1};
    });
  }
  boxOffice(e) {
    this.setState(activate => {
      return { productlist: data.boxoffice, isActive: 2};
    });
  }
  newRelease(e) {
    this.setState(activate => {
       return { productlist: data.newrelease, isActive: 3};
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="categoryList-container">
        <div className="categoryList-text-wrapper">
          <h5
            className={this.state.isActive === 1 ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={() => this.comingSoon(this)}
          >
            COMING SOON
          </h5>
          <h5
            className={this.state.isActive === 2 ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={() => this.boxOffice(this)}
          >
            BOX OFFICE
          </h5>
          <h5
            className={this.state.isActive === 3 ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={() => this.newRelease(this)}
          >
            NEW RELEASE
          </h5>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using three different variable use one and provide them values according to there name that make sense.

```
class CategoryList extends React.Component {
          state = {
            productlist: [],
            isActive: 'COMING_SOON'

          };
          comingSoon(e) {
            this.setState(activate => {
             return { productlist: data.comingsoon, isActive: 'COMING_SOON'};
            });
          }
          boxOffice(e) {
            this.setState(activate => {
              return { productlist: data.boxoffice, isActive: 'BOX_OFFICE'};
            });
          }
          newRelease(e) {
            this.setState(activate => {
               return { productlist: data.newrelease, isActive: 'NEW_RELEASE'};
            });
          }
          render() {
            return (
              <div className="categoryList-container">
                <div className="categoryList-text-wrapper">
                  <h5
                    className={this.state.isActive === 'COMING_SOON'? "active" : ""}
                    onClick={() => this.comingSoon(this)}
                  >
                    COMING SOON
                  </h5>
                  <h5
                    className={this.state.isActive === 'BOX_OFFICE' ? "active" : ""}
                    onClick={() => this.boxOffice(this)}
                  >
                    BOX OFFICE
                  </h5>
                  <h5
                    className={this.state.isActive === 'NEW_RELEASE' ? "active" : ""}
                    onClick={() => this.newRelease(this)}
                  >
                    NEW RELEASE
                  </h5>
                </div>
```